# Can alpakka-xml process multiple xml files?

Tags: xml, scala, akka-stream, alpakka

I'm having trouble using alpakka's XmlParsing Flow

```
val files: List[String] = ... // file paths locally on disk

// simple source emitting the contents of 2 XML files
val documentSource = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(files.head))
  .concat(FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(files(1))))

val contentFlow: Flow[ParseEvent, CustomContent, Notused] =
  Flow.fromGraph(new ContentProcessorFlow)

documentSource
  .via(XmlParsing.parser)
  .via(contentFlow)
  .to(Sink.foreach(println))
  .run
```

When this is run, the graph prints the elements emitted by `contentFlow`, which are correct and match the expected values for the first file. After those, this exception is thrown:

```
[ERROR] [12/20/2018 16:32:23.648] [Sync-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://Sync/system/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-0-0-ignoreSink] Error in stage [akka.stream.alpakka.xml.impl.StreamingXmlParser@36b80955]: Illegal processing instruction target: 'xml' (case insensitive) is reserved by the xml specification
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [44,17]
com.fasterxml.aalto.WFCException: Illegal processing instruction target: 'xml' (case insensitive) is reserved by the xml specification
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [44,17]
at com.fasterxml.aalto.in.XmlScanner.reportInputProblem(XmlScanner.java:1333)
at com.fasterxml.aalto.async.AsyncByteScanner.checkPITargetName(AsyncByteScanner.java:665)
at com.fasterxml.aalto.async.AsyncByteArrayScanner.handlePI(AsyncByteArrayScanner.java:2091)
at com.fasterxml.aalto.async.AsyncByteArrayScanner.nextFromProlog(AsyncByteArrayScanner.java:1064)
at com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.StreamReaderImpl.next(StreamReaderImpl.java:802)
at akka.stream.alpakka.xml.impl.StreamingXmlParser$$anon$1.advanceParser(StreamingXmlParser.scala:55)
```

I understand the basics of what's happening here - the parser is complaining about the ByteString of the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` directive at the top of the second file, but I'm not familiar enough with streams to know what to do about it. If I remove the directive I get a slightly different exception about having 2 root elements.

My goal is to build a graph that reads files from a location and emits `CustomContent` for further processing. How can I rework this to treat each file as a distinct unit of input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat the files as distinct `Source`s, then merge them into one `Source`:

```
val files: List[String] = ???

val sources: List[Source[CustomContent, Future[IOResult]]] =
  files
    .map { f =>
      FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(f))
        .via(XMLParsing.parser)
        .via(contentFlow)
    }

val mergedSource: Source[CustomContent, NotUsed] =
  Source(sources).flatMapConcat(identity)

mergedSource.runForeach(println)
```